# How to view PDF on web, without using browsers builtin PDF viewer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, pdf, pyramid

Is there a way for me to view a PDF without using the browsers builtin PDF viewer like on google chrome?
[image]

What I want to accomplish is to view a PDF, file by file.

I managed to split a PDF file page by page, each page as a separate file.
[image]

I need to view a PDF, file by file, and not scrollable.
When I use javascript to view the PDF, it always open the chrome's PDF viewer.

EDIT:I'm using Python with Pyramid framework as my backend.

```
<script>
    window.open('test.pdf','mywindow','width=400,height=200')
</script>
```

Thanks for those who can help!

Comment: You should use bootstrap model for view your pdf file.

Comment: I think you mean bootstrap modal? I've searched, I think that's not possible.

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava, I'm wrong, its actually possible to view PDF with modal! But there is a minor problem, google chrome is saying "This plugin is not supported" but when I open it on Microsoft Edge, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){

    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal',function(){    
        $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf')
    })
    $('.modal').modal({show:true})
    
    $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('.loading').hide();
});
    
})
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary">show modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working snippet.

Comment: I'll use this one. I'll apply some changes to meet my needs.

Comment: Have fun @Oblivion Coder :)

Comment: This not work. It shows already the chrome internal pdf viewer...